# C++ Converting char to byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, qt

I need to be able to convert a `QString` in this format:
`"0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00"`

To a byte array like this:

```
0x00,
0x00,
0x00,
0x00
```

I was able to do this in Visual Studio / C# like this:

```
byte[] bytes = string.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

However I am now using Qt / C++ and I need a way to do the same thing.
What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the most concise solution, but at least safe, I guess (invalid values are not appended):

```
QString string = "0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00";
QByteArray bytes;

for(auto const& x : string.split(' '))
{
    bool ok;
    uint val = x.toUInt(&ok, 16);

    if(ok && val <= 0xff)
        bytes.append(static_cast<char>(val));
}
```

This might be faster (invalid values are left equal to `0`):

```
QString string = "0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00";
QStringList list = string.split(' ');
QByteArray bytes(list.size(), '\0');

for(size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
{
    bool ok;
    uint val = list[i].toUInt(&ok, 16);

    if(ok && val <= 0xff)
        bytes[i] = static_cast<char>(val);
}
```

You can omit the check in both cases, if all you want is speed.

Comment: Your second option will be faster but initialising the byte array is wasteful since all bytes will be set in the for loop anyway.

Comment: There's `if`, they might not. The point of the second snippet is that there's no reallocation of the array.